# Apache 2.4.10 page not displayed

Tags: perl, apache-httpd, cgi

I'm not a big expert in Apache and I facing with a particular problem. I have 2 server where in the first I run Debian 7.9 with Apache/2.2.22, in the other one I have Debian Apache/2.4.10. In both server  have the same Apache configuration and same dsc-statistics-presenter installed. Below the conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
#               Order allow,deny
#               allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
#               Order allow,deny
#               Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /opt/observium/html
       <Directory />
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride None
       </Directory>
       <Directory /opt/observium/html/>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
#              Order allow,deny
#              allow from all
       </Directory>
       ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       LogLevel warn
       CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
       ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, on Server whit Apache/2.2.22 I can see the grpahs (via link localhost/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher).On server with Apache/2.4.10 , if I use that link, I can see the content of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

use DSC::grapher;
my $grapher = DSC::grapher->new;
$grapher->cgi(new CGI);
$grapher->run();
```

No sure if is a Apache problem or some PERL lib. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type this in the terminal
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2` ,

then : `sudo a2enmod cgi` and restart apache.

Comment: Done but there is an error:

root@T1000:~# a2enmod cgi
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:5
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 5.172.120.59. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Enabling module cgi.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
root@T1000:~#   service apache2 restart

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 5.172.120.59 Port 80

Comment: AH01215: "my" variable $self masks earlier declaration in same scope at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1600.
AH01215: "my" variable $buf masks earlier declaration in same scope at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1604.
AH01215: syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1576, near "$u qw(years weeks days hours minutes)"
AH01215: Global symbol "$u" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1577.
AH01215: Global symbol "$v" requires explicit package name at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1582.

Comment: AH01215: syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1584, near "}"
AH01215: syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1597, near "}"
 AH01215: syntax error at /usr/share/perl5/DSC/grapher.pm line 1616, near "}"
 AH01215: Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher line 7.
 AH01215: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher line 7.
 End of script output before headers: dsc-graph

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with a change of configuration ;)

```
foreach my $u (qw(years weeks days hours minutes))
```